# SOAP Request with .PEM Cert

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Hoping someone can help me out here, my google-fu has not been very prosperous on this issue.. I'm a novice powershell user but have several scripts under my belt.. Hoping someone has run into this before or might know how I can get this working..

I'm attempting to test SOAP requests that require a cert. I would prefer not to import the cert into the certificate store if I don't have to. While trying to script this out as a test I hit a snag with importing the .pem certificate file into the script to use for the request

```
PARAM(
      $url = "https://URL",
      $soaptxt = "soap.txt",
      $cert = "cert.pem"
)

clear

$soapcert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($cert)
$out = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method post -ContentType 'text/xml' -InFile $soaptxt -Certificate $soapcert
$out
```

I have tried several different combinations of getting this to work but keep running into the same exception..

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot
>   find the requested object. " At
>   F:\Development\PowerShell\Scripts\SOAPRequest\SOAPRequestTest.ps1:19
>   char:13
>   + $soapcert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certifi ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvoca    tionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power
>   Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: FYI I ended up just importing the certs into the Cert Store and call them from the cert: location.. This is working fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the description of that dotNet class [from the MDSN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx), it looks like you're trying to use this form of the constructor:

```
X509Certificate2(ByteArray[])
Initializes a new instance of the X509Certificate2 class using information from a byte array.
```

This method expects that the information will be in a byte array, not a pointer to a file.  Try reading the file as a byte array first, and then see if this works.

```
$pathtoPem= c:\temp\cert.pem
$cert = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PathToPem)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I thought I could pass it as a filename due to this [This string input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148415(v=vs.110).aspx).

I attempted to read it in as Byte but got an overload error

'Cannot find an overload for "X509Certificate2" and the argument count"5383"'